# css - Multiple inline-block DIV's to top

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

How do I align multiple Inline-block div's above each other if a larger div is to the left like so:
[EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/corywynn/p5d24tuk/)

I'm trying to make the two boxes go below the other two, but they place them self below the larger div.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="big"></div>
<div class="box"></div>    
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>    
<div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{     
border: 1px black solid;
width: 320px;
height: 150px;
text-align:center;    
}

.box{
display: inline-block;
width: 20%;
height: 30%;
border: 1px black solid;
background: blue;   
vertical-align:top;

}

.big {
display: inline-block;    
border: 1px black solid;
width: 40%;
height: 60%;
background: beige;    
}
```

Any idea how I would accomplish this?

EDIT: I'm aware this can be done by floating everything to the left. However, I would still like to keep the centre alignment from the main container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float:left` to both the classes. Include the child wrapping div.

```
   .child_wrapper{
       display: inline-block; 
       width: 100%;
       height: 150px;
       margin:0 8%
    }    
    .box{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20%;
        height: 30%;
        border: 1px black solid;
        background: blue;   
        vertical-align:top;
        float:left

    }

    .big {
        display: inline-block;    
        border: 1px black solid;
        width: 40%;
        height: 60%;
        background: beige;
        float:left
    }
```

**[DEMO Updated](https://jsfiddle.net/jqr4oobs/1/)**

Comment: I would still like the content centred, this moves everything over. Is there no other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:left` in `.big` class of your **css**. And if you remove the `margin` then add `float:left` in `.box` class also.

**[WORKING LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/p5d24tuk/5/)**

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="big"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>    
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>    
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{ 

    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 320px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align:center;

}

.box{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    height: 30%;
    border: 1px black solid;
    background: blue;   
    vertical-align:top;

}

.big {
    display: inline-block;    
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 40%;
    height: 60%;
    background: beige;
    float:left
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `display:inline-block;` Just only `float:left` do the trick.

```
.box{
    float:left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 30%;
    border: 1px black solid;
    background: blue;           
}

.big {
    float:left;   
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 40%;
    height: 60%;
    background: beige;    
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p5d24tuk/6/)**

Comment: This over rides the centre alignment in the container, as there is enough room for them to go underneath is there a way to do this without floating everything to the left?